# What is gcc doing under a bitwise complement, and a negative left shift count when constrained by integer size?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to eliminate as many gcc warnings as possible in some old code, trying to get "cleaner" code by compiling it with a more recent toolchain.
The code writes and reads registers (or memory) on ARMv6 hardware, I can't say I completely understand *what it actually does* but that's the gist of it for this particular line of the code in question. Side note, all the storage types are `uint32`.

When looking at it on the C source, it's just a bunch of macros with only 1 value being passed on, for example:

```c
writel(readl(ADDR_GPIO_IOTR1)&(~(3<<IOTR_GPIO(26))),ADDR_GPIO_IOTR1);
```

That line and many others where that `26` is replaced by other values (30, 58, 59, which I presume are GPIO "pins") are generating the warnings `left shift count is negative`.

When looking at the preprocessed code, the bit `(~(3<<IOTR_GPIO(26)))` turns out to be:

```c
(~(3<<(~(3<<((26%16)<<1)))))
```

That is **clearly** a negative left shift, no matter the value passed to the macro, that bitwise complement operator is going to turn the result of the shift `3<<anything` into a negative number.

Considering that all those 3 numbers are inferred to be of type "**int**" (they are **signed**), the result of that operation should always be `0xffffffff`, right?

So, `IOTR_GPIO(GPIO)` is defined as `(~(3<<((GPIO%16)<<1)))`. I wrote a testcase to see what the compiler will do in each step for any value of `GPIO` I pass on the commandline, this is what I get for a run with `26` as the value of `GPIO`:

```
          26%16=0x0000000a     [0b1010]
       0xa << 1=0x00000014     [0b10100]
      3 << 0x14=0x00300000     [0b1100000000000000000000]
    ~(0x300000)=0xffcfffff     [0b11111111110011111111111111111111]
```

So far, a negative int32, as expected.

```
3 << 0xffcfffff=0x80000000     [0b10000000000000000000000000000000]
```

Now what is going on here? I'm pretty sure that shift should have zeroed out everything.

```
  ~(0x80000000)=0x7fffffff     [0b1111111111111111111111111111111]
```

So, no, I'm not getting `0xffffffff` after all, regardless, I still get `0x7fffffff` for almost all values (it changes when `0 > GPIO < 3`.

However, here is what happens when I print the result of the whole
preprocessed code with a fixed value:

```
(~(3<<(~(3<<((26%16)<<1)))))=
                0xffffffff     [0b11111111111111111111111111111111]
```

The clear difference is that for my step-by-step test the compiler does not know the value of `GPIO` beforehand, as I'm passing that as an argument to my test program. When printing the result of the preprocessed code the compiler has optimized out the value at compile time and returns what I had expected.

So why isn't that negative shift returning all zeros for my testcase?, besides the fact that negative shifts are *undefined behavior*?

A question to myself is "how the heck is this *actually **working***?" I truly don't expect an answer to that.

But I would like at least an opinion, considering:

- I have replicated the compilation of this bit of code on a testcase 1:1 (same toolchain, same gcc arguments) of the running code.
- I even ran the testcase on the ARMv6 hardware in question and I got the exact same results as on a modern `gcc-5.3.0` on `x86_64` (with or without `-m32`, as I'm storing everything in `uint32_t`).
- There are no other *versions* of these lines anywhere to be found in history, as far as I can deduce, they were added to "support a new chip" (guessing from the couple `#ifdef` around this).

What would the *intention* of the programmer in this case could have been? Even the original toolchain spits the exact same warning, I don't think it was ignored.

What I may be really asking is "how was this intentional"?.

Might it be that at some other point (linking perhaps?) something changes and a different result is being used? Kind of hard to duplicate/testcase/inspect that I think. But I'm going to put a printf there somewhere and run it just to make sure I'm not going crazy.

The testcase I made: [negative_shift_test.c](https://gist.github.com/villavic/3a2b6c3751728daa07f2)

The original, unmodified messed up code: [starts here](https://github.com/villavic/Samsung_GT-S5367/blob/master/common/arch/arm/mach-bcm215xx/board-totoro.c#L3081)

The complete, indented preprocessed line (#L3093 in the linked code above):

```c
({ 
    do { 
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c7, c10, 4" : : "r" (0) : "memory"); 
        outer_sync(); 
    } while (0); 
    (
        (void)(
            (void)0,
            *(volatile unsigned int *)(((((0x088CE000) - 0x00000000 + 0xf0000000) + 0x004))) = 
            (( u32) (( __le32)(__u32)(
                ({ 
                    u32 __v = ({ 
                        u32 __v = (( __u32)(__le32)(( __le32) ((void)0, *(volatile unsigned int *)(((((0x088CE000) - 0x00000000 + 0xf0000000) + 0x004)))))); 
                        __v;
                    });
                    __asm__ __volatile__ ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c7, c10, 4" : : "r" (0) : "memory");
                    __v; 
                }) & (~(3<<(~(3<<((26%16)<<1))))) /* sits here unmolested */
            )))
        )
    ); 
});
```

(read address, bitwise `&` (AND) the result of the read and write that back to the same address, if I understood it correctly).

Comment: Bah... Can you reduce the question a bit? I see many words and some hardly readable code in the end. It might be a very interesting question, but the majority will just skip it..

Comment: That code looks awful. And a negative shift count invokes undefined behaviour. No need for further investigation.

Comment: My guess would be that the original code is buggy and should really be `writel(readl(ADDR_GPIO_IOTR1)&IOTR_GPIO(26),ADDR_GPIO_IOTR1);`. Which would make more sense.  EDIT: That would clear some bits to 0, but maybe the intention was to set them to 1's.

Comment: I make no promises, but I'd expect gcc to follow a behavior i've noticed quite often with "out of bounds" shifts: applying *modulo bitsize* to the bits-to-shift count.

Comment: It's not a very interesting question and it is indeed awful code. The wall of text is kind of a must because I'm analyzing (alongside questioning it) the behavior of gcc when presented with such a case.

Comment: @Medinoc could you expand on that or link a reference?

Comment: Don't know how exacly the C standard defines negative shift count (perhaps undefined behavior). But, for some enlightenment, I already used it in Java because it takes only the 5 lsb of the count (so `x << -1` is the same as `x << 31`, i.e., shift the lsb to the sign-bit; `x << -1 >> -1` produces either `0`, for even `x`, or `-1` for odd `x`).

Comment: @Medinoc: Unlikely, at least if the count is not constant. That depends on libgcc and/or the CPU. gcc does not behave consistent and a difference version/optimisation might behave differently. There is a good reason this is UB.

Comment: @rslemos: I already provided that in a comment. A negative or out-of range (i.e. bitsize or larger) shiftcount is UB.

Comment: @Olaf But that doesn't answer the question of "right now, it accidentally works. How do I convert it into a *defined* behavior that does whatever it's doing now?"

Comment: @Medinoc: TL;DR,, but you should find out what the code is supposed to do, then re-implement correctly using standard types (`uint32` is none!). SO is no consulting site or coding service.

Comment: In reality the question is just "_what is it doing now?_" The conversion into a defined behavior and correct re-implementation that's **my** job, not SO's as @Olaf implied. That aside, `uint32` are only in my testcase and it's just  short for `typedef uint32_t u32` after including `<inttypes.h>`. The macro in question expands all types to (basically) `__u32` which is a `typedef unsigned int __u32`, which is a _standard type_. I've used `uint32_t` in my testcase to avoid getting 64bit types when compiling on `x86_64`.

Comment: Use the `stdint.h` types directly, do not `typedef` some homebrew type, that is bad coding style. And names starting with double underscore are reserved by the standard for the implementation. You must not use them in your own code! And no, `__u32` is **not** a standard type.

Comment: What you fail to realize is that all of these typedef are part of the Linux Kernel, the original (bad) code is what uses them, my testcase merely _mimics_ that using the closest available from glibc.

Comment: @Olaf: "... *undefined behaviour. No need for further investigation*" -- In an ideal world, perhaps. The problem here is that the existing legacy code, which apparently *works*, has behavior not defined by the C standard. The OP needs to figure out how it works and rewrite it to something that will works and has defined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: OP asks how gcc behaves. I wrote it is undefined, thus can/will vary. Conclusion is he has to catch this and work-around. Sounds quite like a "real world" comment to me.

Comment: @Olaf: *The OP needs to figure out how it works and rewrite it to something that will works and has defined behavior.* -- sounds like "further investigation" to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One side of the problem is just this:

> I wrote a testcase

As you said yourself, you wrote a testcase for an unreadable piece of code that happens to work despite hitting undefined behavior. That's really not a big surprise that your testcase does something unexpected, and different. Touching anything in that code can dispel the magic, you can't just deconstruct it and run it bit by bit. Changing the toolchain can also break it, BTW.

Without digging further into what gcc might do with the code, assuming that the facts are all true, this question is unanswerable because it contains a contradiction:

> So why isn't that negative shift returning all zeros for my testcase?,
>   besides the fact that negative shifts are undefined behavior?

You seem to expect *undefined* behavior to have some *defined* behavior...

OTOH, the question below is easy to answer:

> A question to myself is "how the heck is this actually working?" I
>   truly don't expect an answer to that.

The answer is "why not ?". UB can be the behavior that the author expects, as it's "defined" (hum) as **any** behavior.

So the actual problem is this:

> The code writes and reads registers (or memory) on ARMv6 hardware, I
>   can't say I completely understand what it actually does

You can't refactor it without understanding it. That involves finding the author, and torturing him (or her) if necessary. No need to torture other innocent people.

**PS** oh and that question is easy too:

> What would the intention of the programmer in this case could have
>   been? Even the original toolchain spits the exact same warning, I
>   don't think it was ignored.

That's called an *evil programmer*. One more reason to find him.

**PPS** I'm betting on a bug, the author forgot that IOTR_GPIO already does the `~(3<<` shift and does it twice. The to-infinity-and-beyond 2nd shift doesn't make sense.

Comment: While as a programmer I wholeheartedly agree with every one of your points, as a hobbyist hacker I need to have some `faith` that such _evilness_ can be _reverse engineered_. Having said that, trying not to sound hypocritical (as, a _proper_ hacker would reverse engineer this shit by himself w/o any help) I wrote this question on SO for two reasons: first, see some brainstorming around it, second put the wrongdoings of the evil programmer in a context that could be called "_a problem to be solved_" it makes it easier (for myself at least) to figure out "_the solution_".

Comment: @Javier I understand, but I fear that just source code + brainpower is not enough (*mine* is not enough, that's for sure). Don't you have some docs and/or test hardware ?

Comment: I do have the test hardware (a cellphone) but every single "debug printk" I place around these lines always return the same values regardless of the toolchain I compile (the kernel) with, that negative shift always returns `0xffffffff` which is the _expected_ UB. Given that the operation performed ends up being (roughly) `u32 val = &mem; &mem = (val & 0xffffffff)`, all the code it's doing, as far as I can see, is reading a value and writting it back without making any changes to it.

Comment: "which is the expected UB" => do you have a source for that ? If the code is doing nothing, why not try removing it, is it possible to test that hypothesis on the device ?

Comment: The source for that statement is me shifting the bits myself and then casting the result to an `unsigned int` (as undefined as it may be, I really think the compiler infers the types inside the macro to `long` after the second shift and the optimized cast to `unsigned int` ends up with that value, again, I could be 100% wrong and that preprocessed bag of batshit crazy code is actually doing something that I cannot really `printk()` to inspect).

Comment: One of the reasons why I haven't commented out that code is that alongside this source file, there are preset other 4 or 5 similar files that deal with different _flavors_ of the same SoC. Each one of them has the same `_init` function that performs the same calls with the same macros using different GPIO pins as values, which pushes me away from the _evil programmer_ theory, It's hard to dismiss that initialization considering how many "things" are glued in that little chip's GPIO interfaces and how the other boards have the exact same code in them, but pointing to different pins.

Comment: So it's doing *something*. Do you have some documentation of the chip ?

Comment: (BTK) OK, my best *guess*: it's a bug, the author forgot that IOTR_GPIO already does the `~(3<<` stuff and does it twice. Otherwise it really doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: That is the conclusion I have reached myself after looking at the code for different "releases" of the source for different (but still _somewhat_ similar) boards. Add that bit to your answer and I'll accept it if you'd like. I'll write my own "process" as an answer as well.

Comment: @Javier thanks for accepting the answer, I already had edited it. There's still something not quite right in it, as the "why is it working" part is missing a crucial possible answer ("it's not"), but I'll leave it at that, not to spoil the final twist in the mystery case :-)

Comment: I figured out _why_ it was working after looking at the `printk()`'s I had added again after testing the fix. The mask generated by the macro silences only two bits that are never set for each of the values being read->masked->written, so the negative shifted mask that didn't silence anything `0xffffffff` (that's _always_ the compiler's _optimized-out_ value) was no different than, say, a `0xffffcfff` mask. Having said that, there is one case where it it **didn't** work, and that was after a cold boot (battery swap), so the hardware now _properly_ initializes even in that "corner" case :+).

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, the source in question belongs to the opensourced kernel for a specific Samsung Galaxy model (the `GT-S5367`).

That being said, that model belongs to the `bcm21553` family of boards, for which there were many source code *zip* packages released by Samsung.

In that family the `S5360` is a whole "sub" family with many variants, the `Totoro` board. The `S5367` is *also* a `Totoro` board.

When looking for different *versions* of the same file to spot differences in these lines that performed the negative left shifts, I restricted my search to the S5360 alone, suffice to say I found no differences, every single source had the same *bug*.

After a while testing with many `printk()` in the kernel and looking at the generated output, I decided to search on github for the *dubious* macro itself `IOTR_GPIO`.

In doing so I found many duplicates of the macro definition on source derived from my own *sub* family (plenty of `board-totoro.c`).

But then, to my surprise, a different board, the `Torino` (still based on the `bcm21553` had the same macro definition but without the extra negative shift.

So (I'm assuming) this ended up being just a **copypasta** bug. I believe the intention was to move the `mask` to (or from) the macro definition, but the programmer forgot to remove the code off *the other side*.

The code worked fine because all it does is read a value that is flattened against a mask (created by this macro) and then write it back on the same spot.

Since the actual, working, mask just positions two zero bits across depending on the GPIO pin, when the value being read (and bitwise `&`'ded) has those two bits also cleared  then the full, bogus, `0xffffffff` mask results in no difference against the *proper* mask, and thus the code works fine, even with such a **nasty** bug in place.

TL;DR, as @ilya pointed out in a comment, the correct macro definition is:

```
#define IOTR_GPIO(GPIO) ((GPIO%16)<<1)
```

No negative shift there to worry about, the bitwise complement is done *afterwards* to create the actual mask and not to shift bits again.

With that change the code compiles without warnings and works just fine as before.

**PS** Thanks @ilya for helping the brainstorming out :+).